# Send java email failed after several hours in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I use Amazon SES service to send email in tomcat6. It can only send email success for several hours and then it will send email failed. If I reboot the tomcat6, it will send email success again for several hours and then failed. This problem has been bothering me for a several days.
Does any body has encountered this problem? please help me, thanks.

### //Send email code:

```
public class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    String userName = null;
     String password = null;
     public MyAuthenticator() {
     }
     
     public MyAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
        this.userName = username;
        this.password = password;
     }
     
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
     }
}


//send email
public class SimpleMailSender {
    public final static String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    public final static int PORT = 25;
    public final static String FROM_ADDRESS = "service@kkmcn.com";
    public final static String TO_ADDRESS = "xx@gmail.com";
    public final static String USER = "xx";
    public final static String PASSWORD = "xxx";
    
    public static void sendTestEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            p.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
            p.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
            p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            p.put("mail.debug", "true");

            MyAuthenticator authenticator = new MyAuthenticator(USER, PASSWORD);
            Session sendMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, authenticator);
              
            Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(sendMailSession);
            Address from = new InternetAddress(FROM_ADDRESS);
            mailMessage.setFrom(from);
            Address to = new InternetAddress(TO_ADDRESS);
            mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            mailMessage.setSubject("Test");
            mailMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
            
            Multipart mainPart = new MimeMultipart();
            BodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
            html.setContent("Test", "text/html; charset=utf-8");    
            mainPart.addBodyPart(html);
            mailMessage.setContent(mainPart);

            Transport.send(mailMessage);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

**Error information when send email failed:**
-----------------------------------------
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1488591277 A0o81GaPHjNAz0NyRkfI
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", port: 25

EHLO ip-172-31-15-212.ec2.internal
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 220 Ready to start TLS

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at mail.SimpleMailSender.sendHtmlMail(SimpleMailSender.java:97)
    at cla.communication.sendmail(communication.java:2577)
    at cla.communication.getpasswd(communication.java:1821)
    at cla.communication.doPost(communication.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: You should be defining this mail connection as a Resource in your Context.xml. That will save you a lot of code and give you an external place for all these configuration items, including the password. No `Authenticator` requried.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's ignoring your starttls properties.  Try fixing the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and see if that helps.

What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: You might want to upgrade to the [current version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: I update the java mail version to 1.5.5, but it still send email failed after several hours.  

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2046)
 at

Comment: I can't explain why it would work for hours and then fail with that exception.  Perhaps it's due to some network failure or running out of memory or something like that?  It's interesting that changing only the version of JavaMail changes the failure mode completely.